# Is commenter notification case sensitive?

Tags: support, comments

I added a comment to this SO question [convert date format from 'DD\MM\YYYY' to 'MM\DD\YYYY' in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8243392/convert-date-format-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-mm-dd-yyyy-in-ssis)

The OP replied to my comment but I didn't receive any notification in global inbox.

Is the commenter name case sensitive or are those three dots following my name prevented me from getting the notification?

I searched commenter notification case sensitive but didn't notice any question related to this issue. Just curious to know what happened here.

Comment posted by OP in response to my comment:

[image: Comment]

No notification in my inbox:

[image: No notification]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not case-sensitive. The problem are the dots directly after the name, you need a space after the name so that it knows where your username ends. So `@siva` should work, what actually is there is `@siva...can` and that doesn't fit to your username.

Comment: Far to quick for me. I had written "No" by the time you'd written & posted your answer :P

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I thought it always used just the first three characters after the `@` symbol to match the user name. I am curious to know why a space is needed to find where the commenter name ends.